# XMLSerializer in IE9 compatability mode not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, dom, xmlserializer

I have this code:

```
.... 
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        function showResponse(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form)  {
            var myxml = responseText;
            var serializer = new XMLSerializer(); 
            var xmltostring = serializer.serializeToString(myxml);
```

It works fine in all browsers except IE9 when IE9 is in compatability mode. For reasons we won't go into the client needs to run IE9 in compatability mode so I am trying to find a solution.

The error that is reported is:

```
'XMLSerializer' is undefined
```

Does anybody know a way to deal with this? Is there another way to convert the DOM document/object into text like XMLSerializer does?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up doing something like this which seems to get the job done:

```
var xmltostring='';

if (typeof window.XMLSerializer !== 'undefined') {
    var serializer = new XMLSerializer(); 
    xmltostring = serializer.serializeToString(myxml);
} else {
    if(window.ActiveXObject){
        xmltostring = myxml.xml;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since compatibility mode could be emulating IE8 and down behavior it won't work. `XMLSerializer` works in IE9 and up (*standards mode*). Another method to turn a DOM object into a string is to use `outerHTML`.

Example DOM:

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = '<p>testing 123</p>';
```

Get the string representation:

```
div.outerHTML
//=> "<div><p>testing 123</p></div>"
```

Comment: Sorry my knowledge in this area is sketchy, to elaborate:
So I've already got:
var myxml = responseText;
Can I say:
var xmltostring = myxml.outerHTML;
Will that give a string? I tried it but didn't seem to work.

Comment: If `responseText` is a string already, which it should be, then you are good to go. Not sure why you would want to do anything else with it.

Comment: I don't think its a string, it seems to be an object